# How to convert DataTable to List<T> while watching for nulls

Tags: c#, list, datatable, dbnull

Movie Class

```
public class Movie
{
    #region Properties
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
    public string Producer { get { return _producer; } set { _producer = value; } }
    public int Rating { get { return _rating; } }
    public Image Covor { get; set; }
    public string Description { get { return _description; } }
    public int ReleaseYear { get { return _releaseYear; } set { _releaseYear = value; }}
    #endregion

    #region Private Fields
    private string _name;
    private string _producer;
    private int _rating;
    private string _description;
    private int _releaseYear;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public Movie()
    {
    }

    public Movie(string name, int yearRelease)
    {
        this._name = name;
        this._releaseYear = yearRelease;
    }

    public Movie(string name, int yearRelease, string producer)
    {
        this._name = name;
        this._releaseYear = yearRelease;
        this._producer = producer;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

My attempt

```
foreach (DataRow movieRow in MovieTable().AsEnumerable())
{
    if (movieRow["Producer"] != DBNull.Value)
    {
        Movie movie = new Movie()
        {
            Name = (string)movieRow["Name"],
            Producer = (string)movieRow["Producer"],
            ReleaseYear = (int)movieRow["Release Year"]
        };
        movieList.Add(movie);
    }
    else
    {
        Movie movie = new Movie()
        {
            Name = (string)movieRow["Name"],
            ReleaseYear = (int)movieRow["Release Year"]
        };
        movieList.Add(movie);
    }
}
```

This is my code so far I'm trying to convert a Table to a List. The only problem is DBNull's.

I would like to update the entire table to a list, this works currently for 2 situations, but I need for the List to contain all the information if it exists. I could create elseif statements to handle every possible scenario but there has to be a way better way to figure out if the type is DBNull and if not set the property correctly.

If there's any confusion tell me what it is and I'll explain further.

Comment: why don't you use some ORM like EF, ...?

Comment: If there is nulls, then your variable types should be nullable. Then use the `as` keyword to try and cast: `movieRow["Producer"] as string`. Also, you should save yourself some time and look up [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

Comment: I'm very junior programmer, all self taught in the summer. There's a lot I'm missing. I.E. I had no idea databinding existed till a few weeks ago

Comment: Further to RGraham's point, do note however that `as` only works on reference types.

Comment: @RGraham What's the advantage of doing this over having private fields and accessors?

Comment: @Snowfiring Less code. That's it :)

Comment: @RGraham I suppose if I need privates i can use private set. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to incorporate the null-check into the set-statements wherever you need them, using shorthand code:

```
Name = (movieRow["Name"] == DBNull.Value) ? 
              (string)movieRow["Name"] : 
              string.Empty,

// Producer will be given a value if it exists, or null otherwise:
Producer = (movieRow["Producer"] == DBNull.Value) ? 
              (string) movieRow["Producer"] : 
              null,
...
```

You can replace `string.Empty` with `null` or vice versa of course, if that suits you better.

---

**Edit:** Just a very basic clarification, since you state you are new to programming: This shorthand notation means *"if `firstValue` is true, return `secondValue`, otherwise, return `thirdValue`"*

```
var result = firstValue ? secondValue : thirdValue;
```

Comment: Thanks :) Yes i do know shorthand I love it I just forget its order sometimes and try using ?? instead of a single one thanks for the refresher!

Answer (score 0):

One option: you can check `IsNull(column)`:

```
    Movie movie = new Movie()
    {
        Name = movieRow.IsNull("Name") 
               ? (string)null : (string)movieRow["Name"],
        Producer = movieRow.IsNull("Producer") 
               ? (string)null : (string)movieRow["Producer"],
        // etc..
    };
    movieList.Add(movie);
```

Comment: Both are great answers But his came first by 1 min :(